# PhpWord - Exporting PHP to OOXML includes HTML tags

Tags: phpword

I am using PhpWord to take my document generated by PHP and turn it into a Word document.

```
$phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();
$html = "<p>sample document</p>;
$section = $phpWord->addSection();
$section->addHtml( htmlspecialchars($html) );
$objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'Word2007');
$objWriter->save('helloWorld.docx');
```

This outputs a Word document, but includes the `<p>` tags. Any ideas how to display this without any tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are escaping your HTML entities. If you remove the htmlspecialchars() wrapper around $html, your code should work as expected.